# Rails: how get current time zone compatible with ActiveSupport::TimeZone[zone].parse()?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, activesupport

How can a method take the current Time.zone and put it into a format that is usable by `ActiveSupport::TimeZone[some_zone].parse()`?

It seems very strange that Time.zone.to_s returns a string that can not be used with `ActiveSupport::TimeZone[zone].parse()`

`Time.zone.to_s` returns `"(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)"`

But `ActiveSupport::TimeZone["(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)"]` is `nil`.

```ruby
ActiveSupport::TimeZone["(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)"]
# => nil

ActiveSupport::TimeZone["Pacific Time (US & Canada)"]
# => (GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use `Time.zone.name`, not `Time.zone.to_s`

```
[1] pry(main)> Time.zone.to_s
=> "(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
[2] pry(main)> Time.zone.name
=> "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
[3] pry(main)> ActiveSupport::TimeZone[Time.zone.name]
=> (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
```

---

As for how I got this *(as requested)*, I just know the `name` method exists on `Time.zone`. If I didn't know this by heart though, I will check the docs. If it's not in there as you say *(and it is, **[here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html)**)*, I typically inspect the class/module/object with **[Pry](http://pryrepl.org/)**. Pry is an alternative to irb that lets me do something like

```
[1] pry(main)> cd Time.zone
[2] pry(#<ActiveSupport::TimeZone>):1> ls -m
Comparable#methods: <  <=  ==  >  >=  between?
ActiveSupport::TimeZone#methods: <=>  =~  at  formatted_offset  local  local_to_utc  name  now  parse  period_for_local  period_for_utc  to_s  today  tzinfo  utc_offset  utc_to_local
self.methods: __pry__
[3] pry(#<ActiveSupport::TimeZone>):1> name
=> "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
```

`ls -m` on line `[2]` above prints methods on the object *(if you scroll right you'll see `name` listed there)*. You can see in `[3]` I can call `name` directly on the `Time.zone` object I'm inside of and get the output you're looking for.

Comment: awesome thank you... looked at the docs, never saw it. Curious to know, how to you find this kind of thing?

Comment: incidentally, they do include an example of using 'name' in the docs at https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html however they do NOT include 'name' among the 'methods' listed, 'N' has 'new' and 'now' but not 'name' which is why i missed it