# Parsing a TimeZone name string that includes GMT offset hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone, shopify

I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887643/in-rails-how-get-current-time-zone-time-zone-in-a-format-that-can-be-used-wit/13888151) but I am still stumbling around looking for a simple solution to the following:

An API call returns the following format which looks like they are using `Time.zone.to_s`

```
irb> ShopifyAPI::Shop.current.timezone
=> "(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
```

I would like to parse the `"(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)"` into a Ruby class and output the TimeZone name `"Pacific Time (US & Canada)"`

Alternately I could just strip the `"(GMT-08:00)"` offset and be left with a clean TimeZone name `"Pacific Time (US & Canada)"` but this seems like a messy string editing solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ShopifyAPI::Shop.current` returns properties [documented here](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/store-properties/shop#properties).  Yes, `timezone` is one of them, but it is intended to be a display name, not something you should parse.

Instead, use the `iana_timezone` property, which will give you the [IANA time zone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), such as `America/Los_Angeles`. These are compatible with Rails, as well as Ruby's tzinfo gem, and also are used in many other platforms.

```
irb> ShopifyAPI::Shop.current.timezone
=> "(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)"

irb> ShopifyAPI::Shop.current.iana_timezone
=> "America/Los_Angeles"
```

If you want to get a Rails time zone from there, you can use the `MAPPING` constant defined in [`ActiveSupport::TimeZone`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html).  Though I'd avoid it if possible, for the reasons mentioned in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) in the "Rails Time Zone Identifiers" section at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you, I missed the iana_timezone property in the API reference

Comment: @kg. your question is about _parsing_ a given timezone string from an (external) API whereas this answer is about _formatting_ a timezone. How did it solve your parsing problem?

Comment: It was an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/201534). How to get a useable time one identifier from the Shopify API was the X. Parsing strings was the Y.

Answer (score 1):

If you are confident about the API and string format you are going to receive, you can manipulate string as

```
string.partition(')').last.strip
# => Pacific Time (US & Canada)
```

Comment: Thank you, if I cannot find a way to parse the API's Time.zone.to_s back into a Ruby class, then I will go with a string strip solution